# How can we interpret bias-variance graphs with testing and training error curves (graph attached)?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, bias-variance-tradeoff

I came across Andrew Ng's Course of Machine Learning and he has the following plot below:

[image]

I am wondering how we can interpret this graph. The red and blue lines indicate the test and training errors, respectively. However, I am confused what quantifies as high or low bias. Is there a desired accuracy line missing? What also indicates low or high variance? Is it the width of the curves in relation to each other? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/10_Advice_for_applying_machine_learning.html
see: learning curves